# Visting the Cape Town area under the current water crisis

Tags: safety, south-africa, cape-town

We were thinking of landing in and spending 4-5 days in the Cape Town area mid-April 2018. However, due to the water shortage and possible escalation during the next weeks / months, I'm thinking we should perhaps focus on other areas in SA.

Can anyone here attest to how much the water shortage is influencing travel? Are tourists frowned upon for taking up water from the local residents? Are there nearby areas worth visiting that would be less affected?

Comment: I'm a bit biased, because I live there, but the overberg region is beautiful and a great option if you're into nature/walking/hiking: https://www.google.com/search?q=overberg+south+africa&tbm=isch

Comment: @stanri - Thank you - it does look beautiful! If you want to add some detail as an answer I'm sure it would help me and other potential travelers.

Answer (score 7):

Reading through several articles [(for an example,](https://skift.com/2018/02/21/south-africa-tourism-ceo-sees-water-crisis-changing-the-city-forever/) and [another)](http://www.tourismupdate.co.za/article/176825/Wesgro-s-tourism-FAQ-s-on-Cape-Towns-drought) as well as the [Ministry of Tourism site](https://www.tourism.gov.za/Pages/Home.aspx), Cape Town still wants (needs) tourism to continue. They depend on the revenues to help with the crisis. However, there will be noticeable changes you will see: you'll be asked to hang your towels, for instance, instead of having them washed and replaced daily; you will see reminders and hear on the radio shorts designed to bring awareness to the crisis for things like in and out of showers in under 90 seconds, etc.

One thing to note, is that the actual crisis, for now, is limited to Cape Town itself. Travelling inland an hour gets you out of the crisis zone.

So, if you are to believe what is being written, they still want you to head their way for your vacation, but you should definitely expect to do your part to conserve, alongside the residents.

Also, the peak of the tourist season is November to January, and even during that period it is estimated that tourists only account for just under 1% of the total water usage. As you are planning on going in April, the overall impact would be even lower, but it is unlikely that there should be any concern by you then.

Comment: Thanks! can you expound on some of the inland destinations that would be less affected?

Comment: @nbubis Anywhere outside of the city of Cape Town (map https://citymaps.capetown.gov.za/waterviewer/) is fine. The water crisis is mostly due to drought + high population. The areas outside of the city have lower population and independent dams.

Answer (score 1):

As a resident of Cape town all I can say is just follow the guidelines in place. At the moment that is 50 litres per person per day. Thats less than 2 minute shower & you collect that water in a bucket for flushing the toilet. Also advisable to buy 5 litre bottles of water available in most supermarkets. Its a good lesson for all of us not to waste previous resources & be mindful.Many places have jojo water tanks as well which helps.